# Checking when a player has all four aces from a deck distribution.

Tags: combinatorics

Have a deck with $52$ cards - $13$ cards for each of the $4$ types. If you distribute the cards among $3$ players, $7$ for each of them, there are

$${52 \choose 7}\cdot {45 \choose 7} \cdot {38 \choose 7}$$

different ways to distribute the cards - since order doesn't matter.

---

From these distributions, in how many cases will a player have all four aces?

If the **first** player has all four aces, then there are $48$ cards left to distribute around. $3$ will go to the first player, $7$ to the second and another $7$ to the third. So

$$a ={48 \choose 3}\cdot{45 \choose 7}\cdot{38\choose7}$$

Now we have to consider if the **second** player has all four aces,

$$b = {48 \choose 7}\cdot{41 \choose 3}\cdot{38\choose7}$$

and the same thing for the **third**,

$$c = {48 \choose 7}\cdot{41 \choose 7}\cdot{34\choose3}$$

Would the answer be, then

$$a\cdot b\cdot c$$

Or

$$a + b + c$$

?

Comment: Regardless to the correctness of your $a$, $b$ and $c$, your final answer would be $a + b + c$ because it's about diffrent cases which satisfy the answer...

Comment: Your first computation is already wrong: you give 7 cards, not 13, to each player. So ${52 \choose 7}\cdot {45 \choose 7}\cdot{38 \choose 7}$ ways.

Comment: Do you mean "7 for each of them", or 13?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yeah, you're right. I fixed it now, thanks.

Comment: @Omega I see you improved your answer. Now note that in fact $a = b = c$, which is clear by symmetry considerations. Write out the formulae and in the quotient a lot drops out.

Comment: I get $\frac{1}{2\cdot 52 \cdot \ldots \cdot 49}$ as the answer, BTW

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, you cancelled one too many seven factorials.  The answer is: $3\times\frac{48!}{3!7!7!31!}\div\frac{52!}{7!7!7!31!} = \dfrac{48!7!}{2!52!} = \dfrac{3}{7735}$

Answer (score 1):

Regardless to the correctness of your $a$, $b$ and $c$, your final answer would be $$a+b+c$$ because it's about diffrent cases which satisfy the answer.

You only have a final answer of $a*b*c$ when all cases should apply together in order to satisfy the answer.

In short, + is OR and * is AND.